# Why isn't this throwError being caught in catchError?

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am trying to create a pipeable operator and throw when particular conditions not met..  I am unable to throw and catch the error however.

This is my pipeable:

```js
// My custom pipeable
export function waitFor<T>(thisToComplete$: Observable<any>) {
  return (beforeRunningThis$: Observable<T>) => {
    return new Observable<T>(observer =>
      thisToComplete$.pipe(first()).subscribe(x => {
        if (x !== 'Success') {
          console.log('Non success result encountered');
          return throwError('Rando IO Error');
        }
        return beforeRunningThis$.subscribe(observer);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

And consuming code:

```js
const preReq$ = timer(1000);
const dataReq$ = getData();

try {
  dataReq$
    .pipe(waitFor(preReq$), catchError(x => {
      console.log('Code here reached');
      return of('Error was handled either here')
    }))
    .subscribe(x => console.log(`I have result ${x.toString()}`));
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Error was handled here');
}
```

None of the above consoles log however.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-error-propogation-with-pipable?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the Observable construct 
`observer.error` is how you throw

```
    if (x !== 'Success') {
      console.log('Non success result encountered');
      observer.error('Rando IO Error');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get rid error handling in pipe operator. Basically you are consuming error there:

```javascript
dataReq$
    .pipe(waitFor(preReq$))
    .subscribe(x => { 
      console.log(`I have result ${x.toString()}`);
    }, error => {
       console.log('Code here reached');
       // handle error
    });
```